# Compression Algorithms with Constant-Time Seek to Specific Byte?

Tags: compression, lzo

I'm experimenting with building a data-structure optimized for a very specific use-case. Essentially, I am trying to build a compressed bitset of a constant size, and obviously for that use-case, two operations exist: read the value of a bit or write the value of a bit.

The best case scenario would be to be able to read a byte and write a byte in-place in constant time, but I can't imagine that it would be possible to write to an arbitrary byte without making changes to the rest of the compressed chunk of memory. However, it *might* be possible to *read* an arbitrary byte in an amount of time that tends toward O(1).

I have been reading Wikipedia articles, and I'm familiar with LZO, but is there a table somewhere which describes the various features and tradeoffs that various compression systems provide? I'd like a moderate level of compression, and I'm mainly wanting to optimize around memory holes, e.g. large gaps of bytes which are zeroes.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you are doing many of these random accesses, you can build an index (once) to a compressed stream to get O(1). Here is [an example for gzip streams](https://github.com/madler/zlib/blob/master/examples/zran.c).